Убрать scrollbar сохранив скроллинг
Мне нужен div фиксированной высоты со прокруткой контента, но без бара
(только под колесо мыши или жест Android).
Не могу поверить, но нашел только такое решение:
     /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
} 

Неужели сейчас нужны такие танцы с бубном?!

можно еще через js - но будет еще хуже выглядеть
